# Why do I receive no answer after sending a ping packet?

Tags: python, scapy

I followed the Scapy tutorial and sent a ping packet to a website.
In WireShark, I got the reply packets immediately. But not in scapy python shell.

I built a IP/ICMP packet and sent it with sr() but the only thing I got was endless packet reception.

```py
>>> conf.iface = <NetworkInterface [Npcap Loopback Adapter] ...>
...

>>> p = IP(dst='www.bilibili.com')/ICMP()
>>> res = sr(p)
```

Scapy tutorial says I can get a normal answer, but actually I got endless dots

```sh
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets..
...............................................
(ctrl + c)
Received 36 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: my code is all here, the scapy shell input and the result

Comment: Be aware that this code creates an ICMP echo request without payload. Such packets are very unusual and they can by blocked by a firewall. I suggest adding a pyload: `p = IP(dst='www.bilibili.com')/ICMP()/Raw('some payload')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the interface you are using is the loopback one = only local packets. check `IFACES.show()` for the others. My guess would be that you're missing an installation step.
- the answer is never received
- you could add a `timeout=...` to `sr()`

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I think the interface is the issue, and adding a ```timeout``` is a good idea even though it is still no answer.